# can we use SetSpatialFilter function in loop with new filter geometry on same layer in every iteration

Tags: gdal, ogr

I am trying to find shortest path between two point feature. There are many links between two points hence first i make buffer around starting point and select all feature inside that buffer. After this I select shortest link among the selected feature. Then I go to the last point of the selected linestring and make buffer around that point to select the linestring ahead of that point. I keep doing this in a loop till i reach the last point so as to obtain a sequence of link between two point but every time when i make new buffer and pass it as argument in the SetSpatialFilter function it give me the same feature as for the previous buffer.

```
while x:   
 datasource=open_File(path="C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\ABSTRACT\SHASHANK\SHASHANK.shp")
    layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)
    layer.SetSpatialFilter(buffer)
    for feature in layer:
        featureindex += 1
        route[featureindex] = feature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkt()
    buffer=MakeBuffer()
```

Comment: It is unclear what is your problem? Please provide more details and tell us what are you trying to achieve and what is your code doing.

Comment: I am trying to find shortest path between two point feature. There are many links between two points hence first i make buffer around starting point and select all feature inside that buffer. After this I select shortest link among the selected feature. Then I go to the last point of the selected linestring and make buffer around that point to select the linestring ahead of that point. I keep doing this in a loop till i reach the last point so as to obtain a sequence of link between two point.

Comment: but every time when i make new buffer and pass it as argument in the SetSpatialFilter function it give me the same feature as for the previous buffer

Comment: Your comments should go into the question body, please